# Meteor and stripe integration

Tags: javascript, meteor, stripe-payments

I am having trouble getting [this](https://atmospherejs.com/mrgalaxy/stripe) stripe package to work with customers and charges, I can get charges to work on their own but I can't get customers to connect with charges. If I put the `source:token` data into the `stripe.charges.create` a succesfull charge is made however I want to have a customer created as well as passing some metadata to that customer.

Here is My server side method

```
Meteor.methods({

  stripeCheckout: function (token) {

    stripe.customers.create({
      source: token,
      email: 'michael@jackson.com'
    }, function(err, customer) {
      // asynchronously called
    });

    Stripe.charges.create({
        amount: 100000,
        currency: 'cad',
        customer: customer.id
    }, function (err, res) {
        console.log(err, res);
    });



  }


});
```

and here is my client side token creation and call to the server side method.

```
Template.checkout.events({
  "submit #payment-form": function (event, template) {


    event.preventDefault();

    alert("red");

    var amount = 3000;
    var number = 4242424242424242;

    Stripe.card.createToken({
  number: $('.card-number').val(),
  cvc: $('.card-cvc').val(),
  exp_month: $('.card-expiry-month').val(),
  exp_year: $('.card-expiry-year').val()
}, stripeResponseHandler
);

function stripeResponseHandler(status, response) {


    // response contains id and card, which contains additional card details
    var token = response.id;

    console.log(token);

    Meteor.call('stripeCheckout',token,  function (error, result) { } );

    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

This ended up working for me

```
Meteor.methods({

  stripeCheckout: function (token) {

    Stripe.customers.create({
      source: token,
      email: 'michael@jackson5.com'
    }, function(err, customer) {
      id = customer.id;

      Stripe.charges.create({
          amount: 100000,
          currency: 'cad',
          customer: id
      }, function (err, res) {
          console.log(err, res);
      });

    });





  }


});
```